# Datatable > highlight date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am using datatable framework an I want to highlight date which has been passed away

for example now it is 12:00 AM if there is any row how have date and time before 12:00 AM today it should be red

This is the code that I am trying to edit

```
 "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
            if ( data[10].replace(/[\$,]/g, '') * 1 < 150000 ) {
                $('td', row).eq(10).addClass('highlight');
            }
        }  ,
```

basically  my idea is to make this code look like this

```
        if ( data[10].replace(/[\$,]/g, '')  < now) {
```

my time format is like this

```
2016-09-01 05:09:07
```

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dt = '2016-09-01 05:09:07'.replace(/\s/, 'T') + 'Z';
console.log((new Date(dt)) > (new Date()));
```

For more information you can see here: [Converting string to date in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js)

If you want highlight datetime ranges you can increase/decrease Date object state.